# Autofill like windows live

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I want to implement behavior same as the login screen for windows live.

On windows live login screen, input control for login id shows "example555@hotmail.com" in grayed font and when user clicks in the control it disappears and also that id does not come in autofill when user types in.

I have a similar thing to implement where in my page there is one textbox for entering search text. The textbox first shows "Search Documents..." and when user clicks in the textbox the default text goes away and user can enter search criteria.

The issue I am facing (specially in Google Chrome) is when user types in search textbox, he can see "Search Documents..." also in autofill suggestion box.

I am developing this in ASP.NET MVC and JQuery.

One way I can think of for getting rid of this is to turn off Autocomplete for the textbox, but I am not sure that would be a accepted by my client.

Can anybody suggest any solution for this?

Looking forward to a favorable reply.

Thanks and regards,
Chetan Ranpariya

Comment: Please post your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

look at form `placeholders`. this is HTML5 attribute but works in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder). You can provide support for older browser by using [ezpz hint](https://github.com/Eonasdan/ezpz-hint) jquery add on